# Angular JS - isolate scope bind to attribute or parent's attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two custom directives, one is a child of the other. For simplicity let's call them 'outer' and 'inner'. The inner requires the outer and has an isolate scope like this.

```
require:'^outer',
restrict: 'EA',
scope: {
    disabled: '@'
},
```

The outer also has an isolate scope and also has an attribute binding to 'disabled'

What I am trying to do inside the inner's link function is check to see if the value of disabled is true, if it is not set then I would like to use the outer directive's disabled value which I will default to false.

Should this just be automatic, e.g. the attribute binding will bind to the attribute OR the parent scope if the attribute is not supplied, or do I have to use something like $parent to access outer's scope?

Comment: The `scope` property creates an isolate scope so it will not use the parent's attribute on its own.  You could use `link` to get the value from the parent's controller if the value is set there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `scope: true` then your inner directive will get a scope that's prototypically inherited from its parent, so that should give you access to the properties on the parent scope.

Comment: ok, but how do I then set it to bind the inner directive's attributes to the scope and override the parent's values?

Comment: The parent's disabled value can be bound to a property on its scope, which the child can modify. It's best to create a shared object (using the parent controller or link function) to ensure the child is modifying the existing property (and not creating a new one). `<outer ng-disabled="sharedData.foo"><inner/></outer>` << `sharedData` should be available to the inner directive. Changing `foo` should disable/enable the parent.

Comment: Thank you Hank, I have a feeling I'm going to have to find a way to do this with the inner directive having an isolate scope though. It feels like there should be a way to access the outer directive's scope when using require: ^outer. I have access to it's controller after all. The solution needs to be nestable to many levels e.g. Outer > Inner > Outer >Inner etc.

Comment: Ok, if you have access to the controller then it can be a property on the controller instead of the scope. Modifying it in either directive should affect ng-disabled. If you define the controllerAs property in your directive (`controllerAs: 'outerController'`), you can bind to properties on that controller.
`<outer ng-disabled="outerController.isOuterDirectiveDisabled"><inner/></outer>`